# Criando thumbnails apenas com o link do video

Tags: javascript, vídeo, blogger

É possível criar uma thumbnails apenas tendo em mãos o link do vídeo com javascript? Sem ter de usar php, ou outras ferramentas se tratando que quero utilizar no Blogger, ele é um pouco limitado para esse lado. Modelo de link: `http://blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=6ffdd7d2229f9172`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode usar o seguinte código para pegar um frame de um tempo especifico e criar um `canvas` com a imagem da thumbnail, altere a variável `time` para o segundo desejado.

```js
var time = 6;
var video = document.createElement("video");
var thumbs = document.getElementById("thumbs");

video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
 thumbs.innerHTML = "";
    video.currentTime = time;
}, false);

video.addEventListener('seeked', function() {
    generateThumbnail(time); 
}, false);

video.preload = "auto";
video.src = "http://blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=6ffdd7d2229f9172";

function generateThumbnail() {
  var c = document.createElement("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  c.width = 160;
  c.height = 90;
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 160, 90);
  thumbs.appendChild(c);
}
```

```css
#video {width:320px}
```

```html
<div id=thumbs>Carregando o video...</div>
```

Comment: O problema é que os links serão assim: http://blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=6ffdd7d2229f9172

Comment: Atualizei a resposta

Comment: wow, ficou muito bom!

Comment: eu tentei criar utilizando vários videos de uma vez mas está apontando erro no `generateThumbnail(time)` e no `appendChild` https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321301/erro-ao-criar-thumbnails-em-uma-lista