# Erro ao criar thumbnails em uma lista

Tags: javascript

Está apontando erro no generateThumbnail e no appendChild, estou tentando criar a thumbnails de cada video, e os links deles estão nos href da tag a, quero que crie as canvas dentro da tag a ou li, tentei criar contando cada um e executando a função pra cada um, mas me retorna o erro

```js
var time = 6;
var video = document.createElement("video");
var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll("#playlist li a");
for (var x = 0; x < thumbs.length; x++) {
  video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    video.currentTime = time;
  }, false);

  video.addEventListener('seeked', function() {
    generateThumbnail(time);
  }, false);

  video.preload = "auto";
  video.src = thumbs[x].href;

  function generateThumbnail() {
    var c = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    c.width = 160;
    c.height = 90;
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 160, 90);
    thumbs[x].appendChild(c);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="playlist">
  <li><a href="http://blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=203ac83dcf157d32" download="video">video 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=1dbd2acf80b18d44" download="video">video 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=5777446bc907a2be" download="video">video 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

javascript por: Mark Vaaz

```
var time = 10;
var video = document.createElement("video");
var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll("#playlist li a");

function t1() {
    video.currentTime = time;
}
function t2() {
    generateThumbnail(time);
}

for (let x = 0; x < thumbs.length; x++) {
  video.addEventListener('loadeddata', t1, false);
  video.addEventListener('seeked', t2, false);
  video.preload = "auto";
  video.src = thumbs[x].href;

  function generateThumbnail() {
    var c = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    c.width = 160;
    c.height = 90;
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 160, 90);
    thumbs[x].appendChild(c);
  };
}
```

O problema dele é que está criando apenas do ultimo link

Comment: Qual erro é apontado ? Pode dar mais detalhes?

Comment: João, explica +- o que você quer fazer pois você está setando os eventos do player de vídeo, chamando o thumbs[x] porém ele é inacessível, o seu erro é usar a forma errada pra fazer o que vc quer fazer

Comment: Se você explicar o que quer fazer ai podemos solucionar esse problema, só com o erro não tem como.

Comment: adicionei uma explicação +- (desculpem a demora, a vida ta corrida aqui kkk)

Comment: Você não deve usar uma função dentro do looping, ao invés disso declare e função fora do looping

Comment: Eu tentei alterar aqui, mas não tive tempo tente algo parecido com [esse código](https://codepen.io/markvaaz/pen/zLyEdp)

Comment: deu certo mas apenas mostra para um único, não gera os outros links